# IONIC 2 align the title to right in Android and iOS?

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

I need to know how can I align the title in ion-navbar to the right on both android and iOS .

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      my page
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write the CSS as the following:

```
ion-navbar{
  display:block;
}
ion-navbar ion-title{
  float:right;
}
```

Or you can write it in the SCSS format:

```
ion-navbar{
  display:block;
  ion-title{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

Then the title will be displayed to the right and the same will work in all the devices and you don't need to use the specific media query for this.

I hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: it's  not working, the title go to the right over the border, it disappear with ion-title width and height 0, so if i increase her width it appear but it's not a good idea because i don't know how much wider the title will be

Comment: Then I would suggest you to give width in `vw` or `%`, for example, if you give `width` as `100%`, then it will adjust according to the width of the device.

Comment: i find a solution :
ion-title{
  .toolbar-title{
      display:block;
  }
}
it takes the title to the right automagically :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Flexbox like this:

```
ion-navbar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```